# ¿Como unir fechas separadas en distintas columnas en pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ciencia-de-datos

estoy trabajando con series de tiempo en python usando pandas, mi dilema es el siguiente, tengo esta tabla que ya la procese:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo unir el año,mes y dia en una sola columna para trabajar con las fechas, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder responder apropiadamente necesito un dataframe como el tuyo. No está del todo claro pero parece que en tu dataframe el año, mes y día son campos de un MultiIndex (tal vez resultado de un `.groupby()` o de un `.resample()`).

Así que comenzaré por crear un dataframe similar al tuyo, pero con datos rellenados al azar:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

d = []
for año in range(2012, 2022):
  for mes in range(1, 13):
    for dia in range(1, 10):
      d.append({"Año":año, "Mes": mes, "Dia": dia, "NM[cm]": 160+random.random()*10})
df = pd.DataFrame(d)      
df = df.set_index(["Año", "Mes", "Dia"])
```

Este es el aspecto del resultado:

[image: Datos de entrada]

A partir de los niveles del MultiIndex se puede generar una serie cuyos elementos sean ya del tipo datetime así:

```py
diccionario = { clave: df.index.get_level_values(i) for i, clave in enumerate(("year", "month", "day"))}
df.index = pd.to_datetime(diccionario)
```

El truco es crear previamente un diccionario que tenga las claves "year", "month" y "day" y como valores la serie de años, meses y días que tienes en ese índice, los cuales se pueden obtener con `index.get_level_values()` para cada nivel del multiindex.

El resultado lo estamos reasignando como índice al dataframe original que por tanto queda ahora así:

[image: Resultado]

Si esta solución no te sirve porque tus datos no tienen un multiindex, o el formato del resultado que necesitas es otro, házmelo saber en un comentario y puedo adaptar la respuesta.

Comment: siiii, muchas gracias, esto era lo que buscaba